# how to remove specified few lines of an email in Outlook using a macro?

Tags: html, vba, vbscript, outlook

I am thinking to add an unique tag in a "text/html" format email, such as "<>"

And only the content below the unique tag "<>" will be kept and above of it, all the content will be removed.

As html is different from plain and I tried to use replace as delete function but no luck.

Is there anyone can help figure out a script which can help achieve this goal? Is there anyway can remove certain lines in the outlook outbound email, like remove first 3 lines of one outbound email?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you please update your post with what you have tried so far, so it could be a bit easier to suggest some alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `<!-- -->` tags (comments) for the hidden text.

The Outlook object model provides the following ways for modifying bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model which represents the message body.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) article.

The Application from the Outlook object model provides the [ItemSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076(v=office.15).aspx) event which is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an Inspector (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the Send button) or when the Send method for an Outlook item, such as MailItem, is used in a program.

```
 Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application 

 Public Sub Initialize_handler() 
    Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application  
 End Sub 

 Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)  
   Dim prompt As String  
   prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?"  
   If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then  
     Cancel = True  
   End If  
 End Sub
```

So, you can modify the item and cancel further processing the item if required.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. In fact, I thought about to use comment out way to replace the html code of email, however, if email is in "text/plain" format, all comment out code will be displayed in the mail.

Comment: Today, I tried to use " omail.HTMLBody = Replace(omail.HTMLBody..." to add html commented out tag <!-- -->, however, it looks like as only can replace one part at once.  For example, if I replace "<!--", the rest code will be gone and when you replace "-->", as the code has been gone, cannot find the place to be replaced. Is there a way to replace "<!--" and "-->" at the same time?